# scikit learn PCA - transform results - explain why transform does not match dot product of components on original data

Tags: pca, scikit-learn

I have a timeseries of first differences onto which i apply PCA using scikit to get the first PC

```
data = pd.DataFrame( [[1,3], [2,5], [2.5, 5], [2.3, 4.9]] )

pca = PCA(n_components=1)
pca.fit(data)

pc1_trans = pca.transform(data)
pc1_dot = numpy.dot( data, pca.components_.T)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(20, 6)
plt.plot( pc1_dot   )
plt.plot( pc1_trans  ) 

print pc1_dot - pc1_trans
```

i thought the result of the dot product (projection) between the original data and the first components would yield the same result as calling pca.transform but this is not the case, they are offset by a fixed amount (shown below), why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566844/pca-projecting-and-reconstruction-in-scikit?rq=1)

In short  PCA transform shows you the transform on the de-meaned data; so these are infact equivalent:

```
pc1_dot = numpy.dot( data - data.mean(), pca.components_.T)
pc1_trans = pca.transform(data)
```